# debugging shared typescript modules in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for an example project where there's a parent typescript project that imports a local typescript module + debugging works.

I want to be able to set breakpoints in the imported typescript module and have them hit when I debug via vscode F5 \ debugger.

Or if i'm stepping through the code in the parent application and want to step into the imported module code. I want it to step into the Typescript code, not step into the transpiled code.

Has anyone seen a setup that works like this? I've seen multiple questions asked in a similar fashion but can't find anything that works.